# localhost refused to connect in chrome mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, webpack, localhost

I am using webpack-dev-server. Using this command to run the server: `npm run dev`. When I use `npm start`, it works fine, but dont want to do that as it is for production.
So far my server was running fine at http://localhost:3000.

All of a sudden, today, it stopped working n chrome but works fine on other browsers like safari and firefox.

[image]

I have cleared the cache, browsing data. Also re-installed chrome. 
But still the same issue. Any solutions?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I think I have the same issue..

Answer (score 1):

Recently I too faced the same issue, and i found a solution as well.
here is my solution :
Inside Proxy settings, under bypass proxy settings for these Hosts and Domains,
just put localhost:3000, for me its working.