# React projects npm start not working says localhost rufused to connect

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to run a react app on a new machine and when I run NPM start I get an error message.

```
  throw err;
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at module.exports (/Users/wesleymcghee/codingProjects/practice/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/Users/wesleymcghee/codingProjects/practice/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at /Users/wesleymcghee/codingProjects/practice/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:452:10
    at /Users/wesleymcghee/codingProjects/practice/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:323:13
    at /Users/wesleymcghee/codingProjects/practice/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /Users/wesleymcghee/codingProjects/practice/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (/Users/wesleymcghee/codingProjects/practice/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at /Users/wesleymcghee/codingProjects/practice/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:59:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

I also get a message on the browser saying localhost refused to connect.  I have tried changing localhost to 127.0.0.1, but that doesn't work.  I am on a mac.

Comment: There is an answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40841071/localhost-refused-to-connect-in-chrome-mac) that shares the solution for this error. Maybe it can help too you.

Answer (score 0):

If you used `npx` and didn't work try this:

1. ```sh
   npm installl yarn
   ```
2. ```sh
   yarn create react-app my-app
   ```
3. then:

   ```sh
   yarn start
   ```

Answer (score 0):

So after a few hours of digging around the internet, I found the solution, or a work around. I put:

`export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider`

into a terminal in the directory I was using.  The original fourm post I found this on is right [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532).